# All Office 2013 programs show (2) after the name when hovering over task bar

Tags: microsoft-office

All of my Office 2013 applications are currently pinned to the task bar. When I hover over them they have a (2) next to them e.g. Excel (2)

I thought it might be a duplicate install, but when I remove (via Add or remove) Office 2013 and reinstall it does not fix the issue.

Does anyone know why this is happening? If so, how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the name of the **shortcut**, not application name. So there's no duplicate here. You can simply right click the shortcut and rename it to remove the `(2)` part

Comment: I tried When I attempt to rename the shortcut it changes to (3.) However, this did give me the idea to search the App Data folder. I was able to find the issue. There were duplicates in the User Pinned > TaskBar folder.